# universal loading animation for location.href changes

Tags: javascript, ajax, animation, hook, loading

A customer's site we show in an iFrame is extremely slow (~7s). 
We can only provide a JavaScript file the customer will include, but he won't do more than that.

Is it possible for me to hook to all events (forms submitted, links clicked) and display a nice loading animation until the page is fully loaded?

Or can I universally ajax-ify his site?

Comment: Any code do you have, which is not confidential? Coz without that, we won't be able to say anything.

Comment: posting code wouldn't make sense, it might change at any time, and even be a completely different (but also slow) site in a few weeks.

I need a set-it-and-forget-it solution for all <a href> and form submits

Answer (score 0):

Once your page is unloaded and the other page starts loading, the code from the original page is no longer available or running so it can't be doing anything and the content from the original page has been cleared so it can't be showing anything.

In that same situation, the next page is in the process of being loaded and it's code is not yet running.

Thus, you cannot use normal page javascript to run something throughout the loading of a new page.  To do something like this, you would either have to use frames with progress showing in one frame while content loading in another frame or perhaps use a browser plug-in.

You can know when a page is being unloaded with the `beforeunload` event, but as soon as the next page starts to load, any code assigned to this will no longer be running and the current document will have been cleared.

Comment: thanks! before spending too much time on the HTML for this...I'm able to get messages to the console with `$(window).bind('beforeunload')`, couldn't I also open the loading-overlay, or is there a difference between console and the actual page in that context?

Comment: @nachtmann.it - You could put a loading-overlay into the page at beforeunload, but the page is going to be cleared pretty soon when the next page starts loading.  I doubt it would be very useful, but you can try it and see if it's up there long enough before getting cleared to be of use.